# Expression Engine - htaccess to hide index.php is not working. Why?

Tags: expressionengine

I have an MSM install with four (licensed) sites. Three of them work perfectly and behave as they should. The fourth one, currently under construction seems to have a mind of its own. The home page shows up but attempts to add additional templates or template groups with content do not display. I only get

> The requested URL /template-name/ was not found on this server.

I double checked and made sure the Enable Strict URLs was set to No and the templates are all synched properly. At this point I am repeating myself. Any clues?

### Edited

I found out that if I insert index.php into the URL the other pages and templates will show, which leads me to believe that I have something wrong with the htacess file.

Here is the code I am using (which has worked just fine for other sites):

```
# BEGIN ExpressionEngine Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# END ExpressionEngine Rewrite
```

Any clues why this is not working correctly?

Comment: Have you tried all possible ways to access templates? /index.php/template-name, /index.php/template-group/template-name and /template-group/template-name? Also disable your htaccess to ensure it's not that causing problems.

Comment: Hi Peter, it does show up if I add index.php to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the htaccess file. I replaced the rewrite noted above with the following and it solved the problem:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```